# CSS background color for nested <div> won't show

Tags: css, background-color

I'm trying to create an online calculator as a means to help me learn HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I am trying to create the "buttons" as nested boxes in the main container. The container and "screen" show just fine but I can't get the background color to show for the first "button" I have tried to make. Below are the HTML and CSS files I have thus far. Any suggestions?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
 <head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "calculator.css">
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "calculator.js"></script>

<title>Quick Calculator</title>
 </head>
  <body>
<div id = "wrapper1">
    <div id = "screen">

    </div>

    <div id = "7button">

    </div>          
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper1{
background-color: #777;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
height: 28em;
width: 22em;
padding-top: 0.3em;
padding-left: 0.3em;
padding-right: 0.3em;
vertical-align: middle;
margin: 0 auto;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 1.5px #555
}

#screen{
height: 10em;
width: 20em;
margin: 1em 1em;
background-color: #C8F56E;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
box-shadow: 3px 3px #94B551 inset;
}

#7button{
margin: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
height: 1.5em;
width: 3.5em;
background-color: #000;
/*-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 1.5px #111;*/
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS ID's cannot start with a number.  Change it to button7 instead.

Answer (score 2):

you can't use digit as leading character for an 'id' attribute. Check out http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2

Answer (score 0):

IDs shouldn't begin with numbers. Change the ID from 7button to sevenButton.

Answer (score 0):

you can't put numbers as 1st char on css styles

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Paradise/fZ2Ew/)